# Access static variable from within a class

Tags: php, class, methods, static

Simple question, is it possible to access a static variable from a `$this->` call?

```
class testA
{
    public static $var1 = "random string";

    // current solution
    public function getVar()
    {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}

class testB
{
    private $myObject;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myObject = new testA();

        // This line is the question
        echo $this->myObject::var1;

        // current solution
        echo $this->myObject->getVar();
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I've answered my own question. But having a few static variables I didn't want to have a function for each variable, Or even a single `getVar($staticVar)` when I could access it directly.

If this is the only solution. Any recommendations on a better way to implement this.

If I'm going to require a function call for each, I might as well get rid of the static variables altogether.

```
//method
public function staticVar1() {
    return (string) 'random string';
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. I think I need to walk away from the computer for an hour. Take a break :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply access the variable like this:

```
testA::$var1;
```

So using your exemple, it would be

```
class testB
{
    private $myObject;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myObject = new testA();

        // This line is the question
        echo testA::$var1;

        // current solution
        echo $this->myObject->getVar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah duh. Something I probably could have answered if someone else asked the question. Talk about over thinking it. Thanks.

Comment: It happens to everyone ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the purpose of static.

static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

They should accessed as below if the static variable is in the class

```
self::$var1;
```

below is possible in your case

```
testA::$var1;
```

would do the job here.

Comment: Thanks but `self::$var1;` is incorrect as it's being accessed outside the class. You updated your answer as I was commenting though. `testA::$var1;` would do the trick.

Comment: I have mentioned the both scenarios so you can get an idea about it

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that for anyone else with the same question. It was just a brain dead moment. As stated earlier. Gave you an up vote for it anyway :)